# Wix Bootstrapper: Rules to follow for burn to be cached

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I am trying to find any information how the Windows installer cache is working for Wix Bootstrappers.

For MSIs you do not follow any special rules to be sure a MSI will be cached by Windows. For Bootstrappers (Burns) it looks the same, but I had several issues trying to uninstall the package without original installer.

For me several points are not clear:

- how to uninstall a product without original .exe installer?
- will .exe installer be cached by default during installation?
- does custom user interface affects Windows caching rules for .exe installers?

Comment: WiX Bootstrapper is the part of WiX that is unrelated to Windows Installer.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into your registry and find "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", you should be able to find a registry key corresponding to your installer package. There should be one for the bundle itself and one for each .msi installed as part of the bundle. If you find the correct key for the bundle, it will have a value called "UninstallString". This is the string you should use to manually uninstall the package via the command line.

For your second point, Windows automatically caches installed burn bundles. The same registry key you found in the step above will have another value called "BundleCachePath", which should point you to the location of the cached .exe file. This should be under "C:\ProgramData\PackageCache{GUID}", where {GUID} is the package GUID of the bundle.

I can't see why having a custom UI would change the caching location, unless you manually add a dialogue to do so.